# SQL Server query error

Tags: sql-server

According to Wikipedia this syntax looks correct...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.metadata_type ("name", "publishable") 
VALUES
("Content Owner", 0),
("Content Coordinator", 0),
("Writer", 0),
("Content Type", 0),
("State", 1),
("Business Segment", 0),
("Audience", 0),
("Product Life Cycle Stage", 0),
("Category", 0),
("Template", 0)
```

I'm getting errors.  I've tried wrapping the column names in ` but that didn't work either...

> Error code 207, SQL state 42S22: Invalid column name 'Content Owner'.
>   Error code 207, SQL state 42S22: Invalid column name 'Content Coordinator'.
>   Error code 207, SQL state 42S22: Invalid column name 'Writer'.
>   Error code 207, SQL state 42S22: Invalid column name 'Content Type'.
>   Error code 207, SQL state 42S22: Invalid column name 'State'.

Comment: Besides using single quotes - this syntax of specifying multiple tuples in a single `INSERT` statement is valid in SQL Server **2008** and newer only - it doesn't work in earlier versions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SQL Server, string values are delimited by `'`, not`"`.

Also, column names should either be enclosed in square brackets, or left as they are (if they don't contain spaces).

Your query should, therefore, look like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.metadata_type (name, publishable) VALUES
    ('Content Owner', 0),
    ('Content Coordinator', 0),
    ('Writer', 0),
    ('Content Type', 0),
    ('State', 1),
    ('Business Segment', 0),
    ('Audience', 0),
    ('Product Life Cycle Stage', 0),
    ('Category', 0),
    ('Template', 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use Single quotes instead of double quotes for your values and no quotes at all to specify which column to insert:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.metadata_type (name, publishable) VALUES
('Content Owner', 0),
('Content Coordinator', 0),
('Writer', 0),
('Content Type', 0),
('State', 1),
('Business Segment', 0),
('Audience', 0),
('Product Life Cycle Stage', 0),
('Category', 0),
('Template', 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'Error 207' of sql is related to the incorrect column name of the table. I seems that you are trying to retrieve the data about the column name which doesn't exist in the specified table. I suggest you to make sure that your are using correct column name in you query. Also check the table name is correct mentioned in query or not. Try this and let me know if you are still getting same error or not.

if you are trying to insert values to a Varchar using "" try  to use simple ''

like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.metadata_type (name, publishable) VALUES
('Content Owner', 0),
('Content Coordinator', 0),
('Writer', 0),
('Content Type', 0),
('State', 1),
('Business Segment', 0),
('Audience', 0),
('Product Life Cycle Stage', 0),
('Category', 0),
('Template', 0)
```

Comment: your query contains errors: column names must not be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: @FrancisP i'm using Microsoft SQL and it works fine like: INSERT INTO dbo.metadata_type ("name", "publishable");   But i take it out... if u think it's better...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to insert multiple rows with one insert statement, here's another way to do it

```
INSERT INTO dbo.metadata_type (name, publishable) 
SELECT 'Content Owner', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Content Coordinator', 0
UNION ALL
```

and so on